# Multivariate Taylor Terms in R

Tags: r

Given a d-dimensional vector `x` and an integer `K`, I would like to implement a function `f` that returns a vector with all entries corresponding to a multivariate Taylor term as below:

[image: Taylor]

So for an input `x` the output should be a vector with entries corresponding to the `f(x)`

Comment: Did you check the `calculus` package?